# html/js account creation with user profiles

Tags: html, authentication, account

I made a website, and I want to add account creation to it. I'm using my own code, no fancy website builders or stuff like that. I was wondering how I can implement account creation with user profiles where you can type (domain)/u/(username) and see their about me, username, and other stuff, but I don't know where to start. I have a Microsoft account that has access to the database tool, but I'm not sure if I need it or not. I use GitHub and domain.com to host my website. Here's my code, and if someone can point me in the right direction, it would be very helpful.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:#808080;margin: 1%;width: 15%;padding: 1%;float:left;border-radius:10px;">
        <form method="post">
            <div style="font-size: 20px;margin: 1%;color: white;">Login</div>
            <div>
                <label for="uname" style="font-size: 10px;margin: 0.5%;color: white;"><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="Morania-Username" style="height:4%;border-radius: 10px;padding: 1%;border: solid thin #aaa;"><br><br>
                <label for="psw" style="font-size: 10px;margin: 0.5%;color: white;"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" name="Morania-Password" style="height:4%;border-radius: 10px;padding: 1%;border: solid thin #aaa;"><br><br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" style="border-radius: 10px;padding:1%;width: 50%;color: #909090;background-color: lightblue;border: none;"><br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#808080;margin: 1%;width: 15%;padding: 1%;float:left;border-radius:10px;">
        <form method="post">
            <div style="font-size: 20px;margin: 1%;color: white;">Register</div>
            <div>
                <label for="uname" style="font-size: 10px;margin: 0.5%;color: white;"><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="Morania-Username" style="height:4%;border-radius: 10px;padding: 1%;border: solid thin #aaa;"><br><br>
                <label for="psw" style="font-size: 10px;margin: 0.5%;color: white;"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" name="Morania-Password" style="height:4%;border-radius: 10px;padding: 1%;border: solid thin #aaa;"><br><br>
                <label for="psw" style="font-size: 10px;margin: 0.5%;color: white;"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" name="Morania-Password" style="height:4%;border-radius: 10px;padding: 1%;border: solid thin #aaa;"><br><br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" style="border-radius: 10px;padding:1%;width: 50%;color: #909090;background-color: lightblue;border: none;"><br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
```

Sorry if I didn't explain enough or if there isn't enough information. I'm not that great at asking questions and am usually missing important things that I should have said, so if I'm missing anything, ask, and I'll do my best to answer any questions if it helps answer my question.

Also, I don't plan on using any other libraries like jquery or anything; I'm using my own code and only that.

Comment: Longest run-on sentence ever

Comment: You're looking for a framework really.  You should check out Ruby on Rails and the Devise gem (a package programmed in ruby).  Basically what you'll do is hook up a website with a database using an ORM (Object Relational Manager) and you can interact with that data set of `Users` and do stuff like logging in (authentication) and adding restricted content (authorization).  Check out Ruby on Rails, or PhpMyAdmin with XAMMP

Answer (score 0):

So.. where to start..

To clear things up;
`Github` is just Version control, very use full if you want to keep track on al the changes you make regarding project files.

You will need to learn probably some `PHP` for processing on the serverside some Data, `HTML` to build some kind of template with or not with `CSS` for styling. Javascript can give it a nice touch with interaction, but I think you better focus on PHP because that is server side and can process data safer. After all you will need a Database, like `SQL` to store the users.
If you wan't to rewrite the URL you maybe an do that with `.htaccess` `REWRITE RULE`. And you probably want a webhosting where you can upload your project or install something like WAMP, LAMP or MAMP depending on the OS you are Using.

In short, start learning some of the Programming Languages, get a Web Hosting Services and go your way!

And maybe along the way you can ask some smaller more specific Question.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/ have some very nice explanations.

**Update:**
After rewriting your Question , it became  clear to me that you already have a webhosting at domain.com. My advice is to start some Learning about programming Language and ask specific question along the way. Good Luck with your project!

Comment: Yeah I was gonna suggest RoR to start Web Development but things like PhpMyAdmin are really useful for early developers getting into the data management with web development game.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is very nice indeed.